# Next page is not running after the splash screen for 5 seconds

Tags: android

Iam running the following code for splash screen for 5 seconds.

In earlier version of ADT it was running. But now it is not working, please tell me what is the problem here in the code. Next page is not running after the splash screen for 5 seconds. I want to run the splash screen for 5 seconds after that second screen named *FirstScreen.class*.

```
   package com.abc;

   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;

   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Thread background = new Thread()
        {
               public void run() 
                        {
                            try {
                                    sleep(5*1000);
                                            Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),FirstScreen.class);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                    finish();
                                } catch (Exception e) 
                                {

                                }
                        }
        };
        background.start();
    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
   }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead and let me know if it works.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

       @Override
        public void run() {
            // This method will be executed once the 5 seconds timer is over
            // Start your application's main activity
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this),FirstScreen.class);
            startActivity(i);

            // close this activity
            finish();
        }
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: I rectified the problem because I had not made entry in the manifest file.

Comment: Well this code is also working.. Thanks you so much for the support